Error solo en IIS: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
Este error que menciono en el titulo me sale cada vez que se ejecuta mi metodo ObtenerSugerencias, pero lo mas extraño es que solo me sale este error cuando publico en IIS mi web. Estoy trabajando con asp.net mvc con .net framework 4.8, como les comentaba cuando ejecuto mi Proyecto en entorno local con el compilation debug en "false" no hubo ningun tipo de error, solo cuando lo publico en IIS me sale ese error.
Ademas imprimi en consola los resultados de response, y estos al menos en local si me devuelven un json que quedaria algo asi:
[
    "Edificio A",
    "Edificio B",
    "Edificio C",
    "Edificio D",
    "Edificio E",
    "Edificio F",
    "Edificio G",
    "Edificio H"
]

Cabe mencionar que lo que realiza esta funcion es obtener los resultados del metodo e ir reduciendo las sugerencias segun lo que vaya escribiendo el usuario y mostrarle un listado. Que es la parte comentada.
¿Alguien sabe porque pasa esto? Y ¿Como podia solucionarlo?
De antemano se los agradeceria mucho. :)
Este es el error:
consulta_avanzada:395 
 Error al conectar con el servidor: parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at jquery?v=N2YlHnRI7it…k78Q0eabPM1:1:74357
    at b (jquery?v=N2YlHnRI7it…k78Q0eabPM1:1:74474)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery?v=N2YlHnRI7it…k78Q0eabPM1:1:79893)

Este es mi script que ejecuto en mi cshtml:
 <script>
        
        $(document).ready(function () {                

            // Función para obtener sugerencias
            $('#Edificio').keyup(function () {
                var query = $(this).val();
                obtenerSugerencias('Edificio', query);
            });

    function obtenerSugerencias(campo, query) {
            if (query.length > 0 && !edificioError && !lineaError) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/ObtenerSugerencias' + campo,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { query: query },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    timeout: 5000,
                    success: function (response) {
                        edificioError = false;
                        lineaError = false;                        

                        console.log(response);
                        //if (response.length > 0) {
                        //    var suggestions = response.map(function (item) {
                        //        return `<div class="sugerencia" onclick="seleccionarSugerencia('${campo}', '${item}')">${item}</div>`;
                        //    }).join('');
                        //    var h6Title = '<h6>Elige una opción:</h6>';
                        //    $('#sugerencias' + campo).html(h6Title + suggestions).removeClass('d-none');
                        //} else {
                        //    $('#sugerencias' + campo).html('<div class="sugerencia">No se encontraron sugerencias</div>').removeClass('d-none');
                        //}
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        if (textStatus === 'timeout' && !edificioError && !lineaError) {
                            showError('Tiempo de espera superado, no se pudo obtener las sugerencias del ' + campo + '. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde');
                            if (campo === 'Edificio') {
                                edificioError = true;
                            } else if (campo === 'Linea') {
                                lineaError = true;
                            }
                        } else if (!edificioError && !lineaError) {
                            showError('Error al conectar con el servidor. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde.');
                            if (campo === 'Edificio') {
                                edificioError = true;
                            } else if (campo === 'Linea') {
                                lineaError = true;
                            }
                        }
                        console.error('Error al conectar con el servidor:', textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#sugerencias' + campo).html('').addClass('d-none');
            }
        }
    </script>

Y este es el metodo que ejecuta de mi HomeController:
public JsonResult ObtenerSugerenciasEdificio(string query)
        {
            using (_conexion)
            {
                _conexion.AbrirConexion();

                SqlCommand cmd = _conexion.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT nave_edificio FROM CB_Edificios WHERE nave_edificio LIKE @query OR nave_id LIKE @query";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@query", "%" + query + "%");

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                List<string> sugerencias = new List<string>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    sugerencias.Add(reader["nave_edificio"].ToString());
                }

                _conexion.CerrarConexion();

                return Json(sugerencias, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }

Esto es lo que me regresa en "response" al darle inspeccionar:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-critters-container>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>HomePage</title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <style>
            @charset "UTF-8";@-webkit-keyframes fa-beat {
                0%,90% {
                    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
                    transform: scale(1)
                }

                45% {
                    -webkit-transform: scale(var(--fa-beat-scale,1.25));
                    transform: scale(var(--fa-beat-scale,1.25))
                }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes fa-bounce {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
                    transform: scale(1) translateY(0)
                }

                10% {
                    -webkit-transform: scale(var(--fa-bounce-start-scale-x,1.1),var(--fa-bounce-start-scale-y,.9)) translateY(0);
                    transform: scale(var(--fa-bounce-start-scale-x,1.1),var(--fa-bounce-start-scale-y,.9)) translateY(0)
                }

                30% {
                    -webkit-transform: scale(var(--fa-bounce-jump-scale-x,.9),var(--fa-bounce-jump-scale-y,1.1)) translateY(var(--fa-bounce-height,-.5em));
                    transform: scale(var(--fa-bounce-jump-scale-x,.9),var(--fa-bounce-jump-scale-y,1.1)) translateY(var(--fa-bounce-height,-.5em))
                }

                50% {
                    -webkit-transform: scale(var(--fa-bounce-land-scale-x,1.05),var(--fa-bounce-land-scale-y,.95)) translateY(0);
                    transform: scale(var(--fa-bounce-land-scale-x,1.05),var(--fa-bounce-land-scale-y,.95)) translateY(0)
                }

                57% {
                    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(var(--fa-bounce-rebound,-.125em));
                    transform: scale(1) translateY(var(--fa-bounce-rebound,-.125em))
                }

                64% {
                    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
                    transform: scale(1) translateY(0)
                }

                to {
                    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
                    transform: scale(1) translateY(0)
                }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes fa-fade {
                50% {
                    opacity: var(--fa-fade-opacity,.4)
                }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes fa-beat-fade {
                0%,to {
                    opacity: var(--fa-beat-fade-opacity,.4);
                    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
                    transform: scale(1)
                }

                50% {
                    opacity: 1;
                    -webkit-transform: scale(var(--fa-beat-fade-scale,1.125));
                    transform: scale(var(--fa-beat-fade-scale,1.125))
                }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes fa-flip {
                50% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(var(--fa-flip-x,0),var(--fa-flip-y,1),var(--fa-flip-z,0),var(--fa-flip-angle,-180deg));
                    transform: rotate3d(var(--fa-flip-x,0),var(--fa-flip-y,1),var(--fa-flip-z,0),var(--fa-flip-angle,-180deg))
                }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes fa-shake {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
                    transform: rotate(-15deg)
                }

                4% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
                    transform: rotate(15deg)
                }

                8%,24% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(-18deg);
                    transform: rotate(-18deg)
                }

                12%,28% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(18deg);
                    transform: rotate(18deg)
                }

                16% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(-22deg);
                    transform: rotate(-22deg)
                }

                20% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(22deg);
                    transform: rotate(22deg)
                }

                32% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg);
                    transform: rotate(-12deg)
                }

                36% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg);
                    transform: rotate(12deg)
                }

                40%,to {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                    transform: rotate(0)
                }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes fa-spin {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                    transform: rotate(0)
                }

                to {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(1turn);
                    transform: rotate(1turn)
                }
            }

            :root {
                --fa-style-family-brands: "Font Awesome 6 Brands";
                --fa-font-brands: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Brands"
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Brands";
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: block;
                src: url("./media/fa-brands-400-4RSXLDQT.woff2") format("woff2"),url("./media/fa-brands-400-RP3MZ4AX.ttf") format("truetype")
            }

            :root {
                --fa-font-regular: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free"
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: block;
                src: url("./media/fa-regular-400-6ODLNN6G.woff2") format("woff2"),url("./media/fa-regular-400-VE33OVPX.ttf") format("truetype")
            }

            :root {
                --fa-style-family-classic: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
                --fa-font-solid: normal 900 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free"
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 900;
                font-display: block;
                src: url("./media/fa-solid-900-ZZETRIYD.woff2") format("woff2"),url("./media/fa-solid-900-BALFL4QR.ttf") format("truetype")
            }

            :root {
                --bs-blue: #0d6efd;
                --bs-indigo: #6610f2;
                --bs-purple: #6f42c1;
                --bs-pink: #d63384;
                --bs-red: #dc3545;
                --bs-orange: #fd7e14;
                --bs-yellow: #ffc107;
                --bs-green: #198754;
                --bs-teal: #20c997;
                --bs-cyan: #0dcaf0;
                --bs-black: #000;
                --bs-white: #fff;
                --bs-gray: #6c757d;
                --bs-gray-dark: #343a40;
                --bs-gray-100: #f8f9fa;
                --bs-gray-200: #e9ecef;
                --bs-gray-300: #dee2e6;
                --bs-gray-400: #ced4da;
                --bs-gray-500: #adb5bd;
                --bs-gray-600: #6c757d;
                --bs-gray-700: #495057;
                --bs-gray-800: #343a40;
                --bs-gray-900: #212529;
                --bs-primary: #0d6efd;
                --bs-secondary: #6c757d;
                --bs-success: #198754;
                --bs-info: #0dcaf0;
                --bs-warning: #ffc107;
                --bs-danger: #dc3545;
                --bs-light: #f8f9fa;
                --bs-dark: #212529;
                --bs-primary-rgb: 13, 110, 253;
                --bs-secondary-rgb: 108, 117, 125;
                --bs-success-rgb: 25, 135, 84;
                --bs-info-rgb: 13, 202, 240;
                --bs-warning-rgb: 255, 193, 7;
                --bs-danger-rgb: 220, 53, 69;
                --bs-light-rgb: 248, 249, 250;
                --bs-dark-rgb: 33, 37, 41;
                --bs-primary-text-emphasis: #052c65;
                --bs-secondary-text-emphasis: #2b2f32;
                --bs-success-text-emphasis: #0a3622;
                --bs-info-text-emphasis: #055160;
                --bs-warning-text-emphasis: #664d03;
                --bs-danger-text-emphasis: #58151c;
                --bs-light-text-emphasis: #495057;
                --bs-dark-text-emphasis: #495057;
                --bs-primary-bg-subtle: #cfe2ff;
                --bs-secondary-bg-subtle: #e2e3e5;
                --bs-success-bg-subtle: #d1e7dd;
                --bs-info-bg-subtle: #cff4fc;
                --bs-warning-bg-subtle: #fff3cd;
                --bs-danger-bg-subtle: #f8d7da;
                --bs-light-bg-subtle: #fcfcfd;
                --bs-dark-bg-subtle: #ced4da;
                --bs-primary-border-subtle: #9ec5fe;
                --bs-secondary-border-subtle: #c4c8cb;
                --bs-success-border-subtle: #a3cfbb;
                --bs-info-border-subtle: #9eeaf9;
                --bs-warning-border-subtle: #ffe69c;
                --bs-danger-border-subtle: #f1aeb5;
                --bs-light-border-subtle: #e9ecef;
                --bs-dark-border-subtle: #adb5bd;
                --bs-white-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
                --bs-black-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
                --bs-font-sans-serif: system-ui, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
                --bs-font-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
                --bs-gradient: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
                --bs-body-font-family: var(--bs-font-sans-serif);
                --bs-body-font-size: 1rem;
                --bs-body-font-weight: 400;
                --bs-body-line-height: 1.5;
                --bs-body-color: #212529;
                --bs-body-color-rgb: 33, 37, 41;
                --bs-body-bg: #fff;
                --bs-body-bg-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
                --bs-emphasis-color: #000;
                --bs-emphasis-color-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
                --bs-secondary-color: rgba(33, 37, 41, .75);
                --bs-secondary-color-rgb: 33, 37, 41;
                --bs-secondary-bg: #e9ecef;
                --bs-secondary-bg-rgb: 233, 236, 239;
                --bs-tertiary-color: rgba(33, 37, 41, .5);
                --bs-tertiary-color-rgb: 33, 37, 41;
                --bs-tertiary-bg: #f8f9fa;
                --bs-tertiary-bg-rgb: 248, 249, 250;
                --bs-heading-color: inherit;
                --bs-link-color: #0d6efd;
                --bs-link-color-rgb: 13, 110, 253;
                --bs-link-decoration: underline;
                --bs-link-hover-color: #0a58ca;
                --bs-link-hover-color-rgb: 10, 88, 202;
                --bs-code-color: #d63384;
                --bs-highlight-color: #212529;
                --bs-highlight-bg: #fff3cd;
                --bs-border-width: 1px;
                --bs-border-style: solid;
                --bs-border-color: #dee2e6;
                --bs-border-color-translucent: rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
                --bs-border-radius: .375rem;
                --bs-border-radius-sm: .25rem;
                --bs-border-radius-lg: .5rem;
                --bs-border-radius-xl: 1rem;
                --bs-border-radius-xxl: 2rem;
                --bs-border-radius-2xl: var(--bs-border-radius-xxl);
                --bs-border-radius-pill: 50rem;
                --bs-box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
                --bs-box-shadow-sm: 0 .125rem .25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
                --bs-box-shadow-lg: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
                --bs-box-shadow-inset: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
                --bs-focus-ring-width: .25rem;
                --bs-focus-ring-opacity: .25;
                --bs-focus-ring-color: rgba(13, 110, 253, .25);
                --bs-form-valid-color: #198754;
                --bs-form-valid-border-color: #198754;
                --bs-form-invalid-color: #dc3545;
                --bs-form-invalid-border-color: #dc3545
            }

            *,*:before,*:after {
                box-sizing: border-box
            }

            @media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
                :root {
                    scroll-behavior: smooth
                }
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                font-family: var(--bs-body-font-family);
                font-size: var(--bs-body-font-size);
                font-weight: var(--bs-body-font-weight);
                line-height: var(--bs-body-line-height);
                color: var(--bs-body-color);
                text-align: var(--bs-body-text-align);
                background-color: var(--bs-body-bg);
                -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
                -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
            }

            :root {
                --bs-breakpoint-xs: 0;
                --bs-breakpoint-sm: 576px;
                --bs-breakpoint-md: 768px;
                --bs-breakpoint-lg: 992px;
                --bs-breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
                --bs-breakpoint-xxl: 1400px
            }

            html,body {
                overflow-x: hidden;
                background-color: #f3f3f3;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                font-family: Century Gothic!important;
                --sidebar-width: 68px;
                --navbar-size: 56px
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-FLWEVK2S.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-FLWEVK2S.css">
        </noscript>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root>
        <script src="polyfills-BJX5WH5B.js" type="module"></script>
        <script src="main-IUJRBZIZ.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>
</html>


Es exactamente eso: la respuesta no es un JSON válido. De hecho se nota que el servidor está retornando un HTML: ¿qué dice ese HTML?

El servidor te está arrojando un error. Dicho error lo muestra como una página web, entonces al intentar procesar esa respuesta como JSON el navegador te muestra ese error.  Dicho de otro modo: el error que tú muestras es una consecuencia de otro error. En el navegador debes abrir la herramienta de desarrollo (F12), ir a la pestaña red y ver la respuesta de la solicitud. Lo que veras será un código HTML que dentro indicará el error real

@Yussef Ya entre a esa parte y la revise copiando toda la respuesta la cual fue un html, pero no me indica ahí ningún error. De hecho lo que devuelve es el html y dentro de el esta una lista de estilos css, y lo unico que hay entre las etiquetas body es esto: 


@padaleiana Añadí en la pregunta lo que me regresa el método al inspeccionar la parte de "response". Realmente no encontre un detalle de algun error, solo es codigo html y css pero no menciona algo adicional a un error.

Mmmmm... ¿Quisiste hacer un GET realmente, o un POST?

@padaleiana Si, es un GET. Como puedes ver en el metodo que les comparti el cual, es para obtener los resultados de la tabla CB_Edificios.

Ya que la ruta  /Home/ObtenerSugerencias es estática, deberías de confirmar si cuando lo publicas en el IIS es la misma o cambia la raíz. Además como estás usando GET, podrías confirmar tu petición escribiendo toda la url con el parámetro en el navegador y ver lo que te devuelve

Gracias a todos por sus comentarios. Al final si fue el problema que comento @javdromero, por lo cual cambie la llamada de la ruta usando Url.Action, ya que investigando un poco más, es la mejor manera de trabajar con rutas por cualquier cambio que haga el servidor
